# How to implement the rearranging of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, formatting, printf

I have a string named cc:

```
char cc[49] = { "rrrrrrrrbbbwwwgggyyybbwwggyybbbwwwgggyyyoooooooo" };
```

I am trying to rearrange and combine it into a longer string like so (I know this doesn't work):

```
char Intermediary[120] = {
    { ("nn%c%c%cn", (cc[29], cc[40], cc[46])) },
    { ("nnn%c%cn", (cc[39], cc[47])) },
    { ("nnn%c%c%c", (cc[38], cc[48], cc[37])) },
    { ("nn%c%cnn", (cc[21], cc[28])) },
    { ("nnn%cn%c", (cc[27], cc[26])) },
    { ("n%c%c%cnn", (cc[1], cc[9], cc[20])) },
    { ("n%cn%cnn", (cc[2], cc[19])) },
    { ("n%cn%cn%c", (cc[3], cc[18], cc[17])) },
    { ("nn%cn%cn", (cc[30], cc[44])) },
    { ("nnnn%c%c", (cc[45], cc[36])) },
    { ("n%c%cnnn", (cc[4], cc[10])) },
    { ("n%cnnn%c", (cc[5], cc[16])) },
    { ("%cn%cn%cn", (cc[32], cc[31], cc[41])) },
    { ("%cnnn%cn", (cc[33], cc[42])) },
    { ("%cnnn%c%c", (cc[34], cc[43], cc[35])) },
    { ("%cn%cnnn", (cc[23], cc[22])) },
    { ("%cnnnn%c", (cc[24], cc[25])) },
    { ("%c%c%cnnn", (cc[12], cc[6], cc[11])) },
    { ("%c%cnnnn", (cc[13], cc[7])) },
    { ("%c%cnnn%c", (cc[14], cc[8], cc[15])) },
};

printf("%s", Intermediary);
```

This is producing the following output:

```
ooybybyyogbgoogwgwrg
```

As opposed to what should come out:

```
nnbyonnnnyonnnnyognnbynnnnnyngnrbynnnrnynnnrnyngnnbnonnnnnognrbnnnnrnnngwnbnonwnnnonwnnnogwnbnnnwnnnngwrbnnnwrnnnnwrnnng
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked at various forum posts on StackOverflow, but none seem to help me out. I've rewritten the code in Python (it works), but Python to C converters produce unhelpfully long code for a C noob such as myself:(. Any form of assistance would be greatly appreciated or, if you're feeling extremely generous, post example code/functions below. Thank you in advance :).

EDIT:

Assuming Deduplicator's recommendation, my code now looks like this:

```
printf("nn%c%c%cn", cc[28], cc[39], cc[45]);
printf("nnn%c%cn", cc[38], cc[46]);
printf("nnn%c%c%c", cc[37], cc[47], cc[36]);
printf("nn%c%cnn", cc[20], cc[27]);
printf("nnn%cn%c", cc[26], cc[25]);
printf("n%c%c%cnn", cc[0], cc[8], cc[19]);
printf("n%cn%cnn", cc[1], cc[18]);
printf("n%cn%cn%c", cc[2], cc[17], cc[16]);
printf("nn%cn%cn", cc[29], cc[43]);
printf("nnnn%c%c", cc[44], cc[35]);
printf("n%c%cnnn", cc[3], cc[9]);
printf("n%cnnn%c", cc[4], cc[15]);
printf("%cn%cn%cn", cc[31], cc[30], cc[40]);
printf("%cnnn%cn", cc[32], cc[41]);
printf("%cnnn%c%c", cc[33], cc[42], cc[34]);
printf("%cn%cnnn", cc[22], cc[21]);
printf("%cnnnn%c", cc[23], cc[24]);
printf("%c%c%cnnn", cc[11], cc[5], cc[10]);
printf("%c%cnnnn", cc[12], cc[6]);
printf("%c%cnnn%c", cc[13], cc[7], cc[14]);
```

Comment: There are no magic inserts in C. You must call functions for such, like `printf`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Ok, I've now implemented a ton of 'printf's. How should I save the final string? Replace 'printf' with 'sprintf'?

Comment: No idea what your code looks like now. Add it at the end of the question, after a separator?

Comment: So, now you printed it directly. Or did you want something else, in which case you need other functions of the same family?

Comment: @Deduplicator, I would like to save the result as a variable (don't know how to do) and write it to a file (I assume fprintf would come in handy?)

Comment: For writing to files, certainly. For writing to char[] buffers, sprintf.

Comment: Does sprintf ovewrwrite the buffer or concatenate it? Also, would you like to post your recommendations as an answer, so that I can give you The Holy Green Tick and Upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no magic inserts in C.

Instead, you must manually create your string, for example using functions like `printf`.

`sprintf` is good for formatting into buffers, `fprintf` for printing to files, and there are a lot more useful variants.

Comment: Does sprintf ovewrwrite the buffer or concatenate it?

Comment: It always overwrites the contents of the buffer you point it at. Though you can just give it a pointer somewhere into the buffer, so it does not matter. Also, make sure the buffer has enough space left, so maybe use `snprintf` instead...